# cannot create table foreign key constraint are incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I have created users and roles tables and tried both methods of unsigned and biginteger unsigned but still got the problem please help

tried both unsigned and big unsigned

```
         public function up()
       {
          Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->string('name',50);
           $table->timestamps();
            });
                }


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
}




     public function up()
         {
             Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                  $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
                    $table->string('name');
                      $table->string('username');
                      $table->string('email',100)->unique();
                     $table->string('password');
                     $table->rememberToken();
                     $table->boolean('active');
                      $table->timestamps();
                    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')- 
          >on('roles');
         });
     }
```

cannot create table

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? The foreign key should be $table->unsignedInteger('role_id'); but that should not cause any problem.

Comment: In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `orbitcollege`.`#sq
  l-3120_14` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL
  : alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`
  role_id`) references `roles` (`id`))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `orbitcollege`.`#sq
  l-3120_14` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: and also when i hit migrate then i get only users table and not the roles table

Comment: What is the engine you are using? And is it giving the same error when you use  $table->unsignedInteger('role_id'); or a different error?